# python assigning multiple return values to multiple lists

Tags: python, list, return-value

I have two lists `soft_info` and and `bit_filp` which I am iterating through it using list comprehension, and there is a function `update` which returns two values. The code is like below:

```
def update(si,bf):

    ............
    I do some stuff here and update value of si and bf 
    ...........

    return(si,bf)

def main(args=None):
    bytes =256
    soft_info = [-75] * (8 * bytes)
    bit_flip  = [0] * (8 * bytes)
    (soft_info, bit_flip)=[update(si,bf)
                              for si,bf in zip(soft_info,bit_flip)]
```

I want to update `soft_info` with `si` and `bit_flip` with `bf`.

But I get the error `ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack` for the line:

```
(soft_info, bit_flip)=[update(si,bf) for si,bf in zip(soft_info,bit_flip)]
```

I am sure that return is sending back two values like as I checked using print statement in a for loop.

Can anyone tell me why its happening?

Comment: why dont you do it in 2 steps first do the list comprehension then print it so you can see what it looks like then see what the problem with unpacking it is ...

Comment: Give us the whole error, please.

Comment: Also, what is `soft_info_lp` and `bit_flip_record_lp`? You don't define them anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a guess:

Either `soft_info_lp`, or `bit_flip_record_lp` is empty.
So the `zip(...)` is an empty list. This makes the list comprehension an empty list as well. So you end up doing

```
In [84]: (soft_info, bit_flip) = []
```

which results in

```
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension returns you a list of tuples of (si, bf). It looks like this:

```
a = [ (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8) ]
```

To assign first elements of the pairs to soft_info, and second elements to bit_flip, you can't use a simple tuple assigment, instead you need to "unzip" the list into two lists like this:

```
soft_info, bit_flip = zip(*a)
```

Read up on the `zip` and `*` operator.